# This is checkboxlist checked vb.net windows form

Tags: vb.net

I want to add multiple records into database but I get the following error:

`Conversion from type 'DataRowView' to type 'Integer' is not valid.`

My code is as follow:

```
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck

    Dim SelectedMainCat As Integer
    Dim DMV As DataRowView = TryCast(CheckedListBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView)

    If DMV IsNot Nothing Then

        'SelectedMainCat = DMV.CheckedItems(n)

        For n As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1
            Dim userWants As Integer = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(n)
        Next n


    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The type that CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(n) returns is of type DataRowView and you're trying to set "userWants" which is a integer to that value. Try "Dim userWants As DataRowView = Check..."

Comment: `CheckedItems(n)` returns a `DataRowView`. This cannot be converted to an integer as stated by the error message.

Comment: Yes you are right then how to handle it?

Comment: @SheerazBughio First, turn **[option strict on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx)**. Seriously. Then you fix the error by casting it to a DRV: `Dim userWants As DataRowView = DirectCast(CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(n), DataRowView)`.

Comment: Yes Your are right MY Problem is solved but now im not getting numbers in the loop suppose i have checked 3 items then in the loop (n) values is o now in the current time how i get the numbers of values in (n) in for loop plz tell me sir?

Comment: @SheerazBughio Ask a new question as that is not related to this.

Comment: and i am clicking two time in checkboxlist why it check when two times i am click it?

Comment: ok i am not getting checked box ID and names and  its value actualy i want to save them in db can u tell me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks** Now My Code is Working **Thankyou** once again

Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck

```
    Dim SelectedMainCat As DataRowView
    Dim DMV As DataRowView = TryCast(CheckedListBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView)

    If DMV IsNot Nothing Then



        For n As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1
            SelectedMainCat = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(n)
            Dim userWants As DataRowView = DirectCast(CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(n), DataRowView)

            **'insert query**


        Next n


    End If
End Sub
```